# How to add bootstrap module in a svelte JS app?

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, svelte

I'm very new to svelte ( like many of us ^^ ), and I didn't manage to add bootstrap to my app. Tried to run 'npm add bootstrap' but it said that I need peer jquery dependencie. Here is the terminal render

What I don't understand is why the package has been added and I can't still use the bootstrap classes. Second point, why does it talk about peer dependencies? What's the link here?
I don't know if I'm missing something but if you guys got the solution it will help a lot. Thank you

**npm add bootstrap**

`npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

````
npm WARN svelte-app@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN svelte-app@1.0.0 No license field.

+ bootstrap@4.4.1
added 1 package from 2 contributors and audited 9125 packages in 8.047s
found 0 vulnerabilities```
````

Comment: it's just a warning. Your bootstrap was downloaded to a node_modules folder.

Comment: Sure that what I thought but like I said I still can't use bootstrap classes

Answer (score 27):

Your problem is that installing `bootstrap` into node_modules doesn't automatically include the files in your application. There are a few different ways you can accomplish this.

#### Option 1: Copy the files to `/public` manually

1. Download the bootstrap files and place them inside the `public` folder of your svelte project.
2. Add the css link in `public/index.html`. `<link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>`.

The downside of this approach is that you will need to commit the bootstrap folder to your version control system, which is generally frowned upon.

#### Option 2: Copy the files to `/public` using rollup

1. install [rollup-plugin-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-copy)
2. Update `rollup.config.js` to include the `copy` plugin. Here is a snippet of the important parts from a rollup.config.js file from a fresh svelte install.

```js
//...
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'

export default {
    //...
    plugins: [
        //...
        copy({
            targets: [{ 
                src: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*', 
                dest: 'public/vendor/bootstrap' 
            }]
        }),
       //...
    ],
    //...
};
```

3. Add the css link in `public/index.html`. `<link rel='stylesheet' href='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'>`

Comment: StackOverflow should allow two positive votes when someone saves our lives like that! :-)

Comment: I'd love to see the official Svelte docs show ways to handle this type of scenario, because this is an extremely common thing to do! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: If you created the app using vite, you need to add this to vite.config.ts instead. In the export default defineConfig, in plugins, add the copy command and copy targets. You may want also want to just include the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.css.map to save space.

Comment: I was using vite and had to use `import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'` instead of `rollup-plugin-copy`, but otherwise it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is an addition to the accepted answer's second option. (I cannot comment yet..)

Instead of copying all of Bootstrap's files to the `public` folder, you can also pick and choose. For example, I only needed the minified CSS and the bundled minified JavaScript, so I configured the `copy` plugin like this:

```js
//...
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";

export default {
  //...
  plugins: [
    //...
    copy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          dest: "public/vendor/bootstrap/css",
        },
        {
          src: "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
          dest: "public/vendor/bootstrap/js",
        },
      ],
    }),
    //...
  ],
  //...
};
```

The CSS can be included in the `<head>` tag in `public/index.html`:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

The JavaScript can be included inside of the `<body>` tag (at the end) in `public/index.html`:

```html
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also [sveltestrap](https://sveltestrap.js.org/) as one of the Svelte Society [design systems](https://sveltesociety.dev/components#design-systems)

Answer (score 0):

I successfully added Bootstrap 5 to my Svelte project, here is how to do this:

1. You need to have Svelte project, see [for Svelte](https://svelte.dev/blog/the-easiest-way-to-get-started) and [for SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/)
2. Enter the project directory.
3. Run `npm install` or `yarn` (if you prefer yarn) to download dependencies listed in `package.json`.
4. Then add Bootstrap with `npm install bootstrap` (or `npm i bootstrap`) or `yarn add bootstrap`. You can specify version if you want. Its folder will appear among other dependencies in `node_modules`.
5. Since Bootstrap requires `popper.js` and `jQuery` we also need to add them:
   `npm i @popperjs/core jquery`.
6. Now that we have Bootstrap installed (its source code is in `node_modules` folder) we need to link it to our application. Since Svelte app is basically an html page we can simply add links to Bootstrap CSS and JS in src/app.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    %sveltekit.head%
</head>

<body>
    <div>%sveltekit.body%</div>
    <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Using aliases for `node_modules` is not preconfigured in `vite.config.js` by default.

That's it, this worked for me.

Comment: This works until you try `npm run build ` and discover that the bootstrap files aren't find anywhere under `build/`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(async () => {
    await import('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
    window.bootstrap = await import('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js')
    // Some code that uses bootstrep - e.g.:
    const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
    const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
})
```